# Extract text data line by line from pdf using pdfbox API in java

Tags: pdfbox

I have used to extract text data from PDF using Apache PDFBox API, but below code is not returned data sequentially (line by line)

Code:

```
try {
            RandomAccess scratchFile = null;
            pdDoc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(fileName), scratchFile);
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            system.out.println(parsedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Look for line breaks in the parsedText.

Comment: and/or use pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true) if your question was meant to say that the sequence is in the wrong order.

Comment: Good; please answer the question yourself, or delete it :-)